# How to calculate each value between a range of numbers, with multiple ranges?

Tags: excel, powershell, range

I have a series of sub net ranges in an excel spreadsheet i.e.

- 10.0.0.1 - 10.0.0.10
- 10.1.1.1 - 10.0.0.224

I need to essentially expand each range to include individual host addresses, and then list them. i.e. for

- 10.0.0.1, 10.0.0.2, 10.0.0.3 through to 10.0.0.10 etc.
- 10.1.1.1, 10.1.1.2, 10.1.1.3 through to 10.0.0.224 etc.

until the last number in the range is done.

Essentially, read a list of IP addresses (format = `10.0.0.1-10`) from a spreadsheet or txt file, list all the values between the low and high number to get the full range of host addresses, but do this for multiple ranges and export to a text file or CSV.

I have tried this and it worked but only when I input the lower number into subnet.txt and the highest number in subnet2.txt, however, it only allows for one number per file, so it is not scalable i.e. cannot simply list all the ip ranges in one file. And have to manually add the network address in.

```
$x = Get-Content "H:\subnet.txt"
$y = Get-Content "H:\subnet2.txt"

$computers = $x..$y | foreach { "10.0.0.$_" }

$computers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mention Excel, so I presume your data can be exported in CSV format, which the solution below builds on:

```
# Read the ranges into an array of custom objects with .From and .To properties
$ranges=@'
From,To
10.0.0.1,10.0.0.2
10.1.1.1,10.1.1.3
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv  # IRL you'd use Import-Csv with a file.

# Loop over all ranges
foreach ($range in $ranges) {

  # Extract the first 3 components, assumed to be the same in 
  # both the .From and .To values, e.g., '10.0.0'
  $first3Components = $range.From -replace '\.[^.]+$'

  # Extract the last components, which mark the range endpoints, as numbers.
  # E.g., 1 and 2
  $fromLastComponent = [int] ($range.From -split '\.')[-1]
  $toLastComponent = [int] ($range.To -split '\.')[-1]

  # Loop between the range endpoints.
  foreach ($lastComponent in $fromLastComponent..$toLastComponent) {
    "$first3Components.$lastComponent"
  }

}
```

The above yields:

```
10.0.0.1
10.0.0.2
10.1.1.1
10.1.1.2
10.1.1.3
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is in the form `10.0.0.1-10`, you could split it into the 3 variable parts using the `-split` regex operator:

```
$string = '10.0.0.1-10'

# split on the last '.' (ie. the dot followed by '1-10')
$prefix,$range = $string -split '\.(?=\d+-\d+)'

# split the range (1-10) into 1 and 10
$from,$to = $range -split '-'
$from..$to | ForEach-Object { "$prefix.$_"}
```

I'd suggest defining a filter so that you can easily pipe your input:

```bsh
filter Expand-IPRange {

  if(($string = $_) -notmatch '^(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}-\d{1,3}$')){
    Write-Error "invalid ip range notation: $_"
  }

  $prefix,$range = $string -split '\.(?=\d+-\d+)'

  $from,$to = $range -split '-'
  $from..$to | ForEach-Object {
    "$prefix.$_"
  }
}

Get-Content ipranges.txt |Expand-IPRange |Set-Content ipaddresses.txt
```

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help - good idea with splitting it, i was having truble matching the network address to the host address